# Bad input parse error?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to write a program that will help me crunch some numbers for my physics homework. The program itself became lengthy and I only know the basics of Python so I'm sure many things could have been done easier. My problem is that when I try to run the program, it tells me there is an error in line 133, but I cannot figure out what's wrong in the code.

```
def initial_momentum_cm_2(m2, m2U, Vcmi2, Vcmi2U, Vcm, VcmU, Vi2, Vi2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U):
    Pcmi2 = Vcmi2*m2
    Pcmi2U = (((Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U))+(m2U/m2))*Pcmi2
    return Pcmi2, Pcmi2U
intitial_momentum_cm_2 = initial_momentum_cm_2(m2, m2U, Vcmi2, Vcmi2U, Vcm, VcmU, Vi2, Vi2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U)
```

Line 133 is `Pcmi2U = (((Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U))+(m2U/m2))*Pcmi2`
However, I believe that this entire block is correct. Help please, and thanks.

```
print "results given in (value, uncertainty) form"
print "cmf refers to center of mass reference frame"
w = float(raw_input("Enter width of index card (m))"))
wU = float(raw_input("Enter uncertainty of index card"))
m1 = float(raw_input("Enter mass of cart 1 (red) (g)"))
m1U = float(raw_input("Enter uncertainty of m1"))
Vi1 = float(raw_input("Enter initial velocity of cart 1 (m/s):"))
Vi1U = float(raw_input("Enter uncertainty of Vi1"))
Vf1 = float(raw_input("Enter final velocity of cart 1 (m/s):"))
Vf1U = float(raw_input("Enter uncertainty of Vf1"))
m2 = float(raw_input("Enter mass of cart 2 (blue) (g):"))
m2U = float(raw_input("Enter uncertainty of m2"))
Vi2 = float(raw_input("Enter initial velocity of cart 2 (m/s)"))
Vi2U = float(raw_input("Enter uncertainty of Vi2"))
Vf2 = float(raw_input("Enter final velocity of cart 2 (m/s):"))
Vf2U = float(raw_input("Enter uncertainty of Vf2"))
wRU = wU/w 
#RU=Relative Uncertainty
print ("width uncertainty:"), wRU,("m")

#Fix 1: Added "global" command in order to be able to access
# a variable inside a funtion.


#Initial and final momenta of each mass in lab reference frame
def initial_momentum_1(m1, m1U, Vi1, Vi1U):
    global Pi1
    global Pi1U
    Pi1 = m1*Vi1
    Pi1U = Pi1*wRU
    return Pi1, Pi1U
initial_momentum_1 = initial_momentum_1(m1, m1U, Vi1, Vi1U)

def final_momentum_1(m1, m1U, Vf1, Vf1U):
    global Pf1
    global Pf1U
    Pf1 = m1*Vf1
    Pf1U = Pf1*wRU
    return Pf1, Pf1U
final_momentum_1 = final_momentum_1(m1, m1U, Vf1, Vf1U)

def initial_momentum_2(m2, m2U, Vi2, Vi2U):
    global Pi2
    global Pi2U
    Pi2 = m2*Vi2
    Pi2U = Pi2*wRU
    return Pi2, Pi2U
initial_momentum_2 = initial_momentum_2(m2, m2U, Vi2, Vi2U)

def final_momentum_2(m2, m2U, Vf2, Vf2U):
    global Pf2
    global Pf2U
    Pf2 = m2*Vf2
    Pf2U = Pf2*wRU
    return Pf2, Pf2U
final_momentum_2 = final_momentum_2(m2, m2U, Vf2, Vf2U)

print "Initial momentum 1:",initial_momentum_1,"nMs"
print "Final momentum 1:",final_momentum_1,"nMs"
print "Initial momentum 2:",initial_momentum_2,"nMs"
print "Final momentum 2:",final_momentum_2,"nMs"



#Velocity of center of mass in lab reference frame
def Velocity_Center_of_Mass(Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U):
    global Vcm
    global VcmU
    Vcm = (Pi1+Pi2)/(m1+m2)
    VcmU = (((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2)))*Vcm
    return Vcm, VcmU
Velocity_Center_of_Mass = Velocity_Center_of_Mass(Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U)

print "Velocity of center of mass:",Velocity_Center_of_Mass,"m/s"



#Initial and final velocities of each mass in center-of-mass reference frame
def Vcmi1(Vcm, VcmU, Vi1, Vi1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U):
    global Vcmi1
    global Vcmi1U
    Vcmi1 = Vi1-Vcm
    Vcmi1U = (Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2))))*Vcmi1
    return Vcmi1, Vcmi1U
Vcmi1 = Vcmi1(Vcm, VcmU, Vi1, Vi1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U)

def Vcmf1(Vcm, VcmU, Vf1, Vf1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U):
    global Vcmf1
    global Vcmf1U
    Vcmf1 = Vf1-Vcm
    Vcmf1U = (Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2))))*Vcmf1
    return Vcmf1, Vcmf1U
Vcmf1 = Vcmf1(Vcm, VcmU, Vf1, Vf1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U)

def Vcmi2(Vcm, VcmU, Vi2, Vi2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U):
    global Vcmi2
    global Vcmi2U
    Vcmi2 = Vi2-Vcm
    Vcmi2U = (Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2))))*Vcmi2
    return Vcmi2, Vcmi2U
Vcmi2 = Vcmi2(Vcm, VcmU, Vi2, Vi2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U)

def Vcmf2(Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U):
    global Vcmf2
    global Vcmf2U
    Vcmf2 = Vf2-Vcm
    Vcmf2U = (Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2))))*Vcmf2
    return Vcmf2, Vcmf2U
Vcmf2 = Vcmf2(Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U, m2, m2U)

print "Initial velocity 1 in cmf:",Vcmi1,"m/s"
print "Final velocity 1 in cmf:",Vcmf1,"m/s"
print "Initial velocity 2 in cmf:",Vcmi2,"m/s"
print "Final velocity 2 in cmf:",Vcmf2,"m/s"


#Initial and final momenta of each mass in center-of-mass frame
def initial_momentum_cm_1(m1, m1U, Vcmi1, Vcmi1U, Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1,      Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m2, m2U):
    Pcmi1 = Vcmi1*m1
    Pcmi1U = (((Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2)))))+    (m1U/m1))*Pcmi1
    return Pcmi1, Pcmi1U
initial_momentum_cm_1 = initial_momentum_cm_1(m1, m1U, Vcmi1, Vcmi1U, Vcm,     VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m2, m2U)

def final_momentum_cm_1(m1, m1U, Vcmf1, Vcmf1U, Vcm, VcmU, Vf1, Vf1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m2, m2U):
    Pcmf1 = Vcmf1*m1
    Pcmf1U = (((Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2)))))+(m1U/m1))*Pcmf1
    return Pcmf1, Pcmf1U
final_momentum_cm_1 = final_momentum_cm_1(m1, m1U, Vcmf1, Vcmf1U, Vcm, VcmU, Vf1, Vf1U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m2, m2U)

def initial_momentum_cm_2(m2, m2U, Vcmi2, Vcmi2U, Vcm, VcmU, Vi2, Vi2U, Pi1,   Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U):
    Pcmi2 = Vcmi2*m2
    Pcmi2U = Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U))+(m2U/m2))*Pcmi2
    return Pcmi2, Pcmi2U
intitial_momentum_cm_2 = initial_momentum_cm_2(m2, m2U, Vcmi2, Vcmi2U, Vcm, VcmU, Vi2, Vi2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U)

def final_momentum_cm_2(m2, m2U, Vcmf2, Vcmf2U,Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1,     Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U):
    Pcmf2 = Vcmf2*m2
    Pcmf2U = (((Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U)/(m1+m2)))))+(m2U/m2))*Pcmf2
    return Pcmf2, Pcmf2U
final_momentum_cm_2 = final_momentum_cm_2(m2, m2U, Vcmf2, Vcmf2U,Vcm, VcmU, Vf2, Vf2U, Pi1, Pi1U, Pi2, Pi2U, m1, m1U)

print "Initial momentum 1 in cmf:", initial_momentum_cm_1, "nMs"
print "Final momentum 1 in cmf:",final_momentum_cm_1,"nMs"
print "Initial momentum 2 in cmf:",intitial_momentum_cm_2,"nMs"
print "Final momentum 2 in cmf:",final_momentum_cm_2,"nMs"



#Momentum of center of mass in center-of-mass reference frame
def momentum_center_of_mass(m1, m1U, m2, m2U, Vcm, VcmU):
    Pcm = (m1+m2)*Vcm
    PcmU = (((m1U+m2U)/(m1_m2))+(VcmU/Vcm))*Pcm
    return Pcm, PcmU
momentum_center_of_mass = momentum_center_of_mass(m1, m1U, m2, m2U, Vcm, VcmU)

print "Momentum of center of mass in cmf:",momentum_center_of_mass,"nMs"
```

Comment: Please post entire error traceback. For me it looks like brackets are unbalanced on line 133

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean the entire error traceback? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 133 you have got 3 more left brackets than right ones, you must have equal number of brackets for each side in each line.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I was dumb to miss it. Hopefully the next error is just as dumb... What is wrong with this line?

    `print "Initial momentum 1 in cmf:",initial_momentum_cm_1,"nMs"`

Comment: Can you add the code of the function and the error?

Comment: Okay sorry, it ended up being another simple mistake a little up the code. This one is more confusing to me though. "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple on line 132" I will edit the original question to include the entire code and make it clearer to understand.

Comment: If you are using Python 3.x, then you must enclose the arguments to `print` inside ()'s.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a comma inside your float instead of a '.'. Something like `3,14159 + 1.0`. Python creates a tuple object when it sees those commas, in this it would the tuple of two ints, `(3, 14159)`. You can only add tuples to other tuples.  Either that, or you just have a stray comma after a term in your addition, like `a, + 2.71828`, which would also create a single-element tuple, `(a,)`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'm using 2.7 so this should work assuming your second point isn't an issue, checking now. Thanks! PS. full code posted.

Comment: This is line 132:
    `Pcmi2U = Vi1U+(((Pi1U+Pi2U)/(Pi1+Pi2))+((m1U+m2U))+(m2U/m2))*Pcmi2`. All those variables have been converted to float besides Pcmi2. However, `Pcmi2 = Vcmi2*m2`. From this, m2 has been converted to a float, and Vcmi2 is obtained by multiplying floats only, so in the end shouldn't all the variables be floats?

Comment: Just before that line, do this: `for vv in (Vi1U,Pi1U,Pi2U,Pi1,Pi2,m1U,m2U,Pcmi2): print type(vv)`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Wouldn't have thought about doing this. This is what the output is: `<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'tuple'>`. I'm not really sure what makes the last one a tuple if it's the product of two floats. I'm going to double check that now.

Comment: Turns out Vcmi is a tuple, going to trace this back now. Thank you so much for the "check type" suggestion!